# vs code on MacBook // linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, c, visual-studio-code, struct, x86-64

I'm learning double linked list and trying to code it.
I encountered an error and I couldn't fix it after searching for 5 hours.

my code is

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <curses.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    int data;
    struct node *prev;
};
struct node *start = NULL;
struct node *create_ll(struct node *);
struct node *display(struct node *);
struct node *insert_beg(struct node *);
struct node *insert_end(struct node *);
struct node *insert_before(struct node *);
struct node *insert_after(struct node *);
struct node *delete_beg(struct node *);
struct node *delete_end(struct node *);
struct node *delete_before(struct node *);
struct node *delete_after(struct node *);
struct node *delete_list(struct node *);
int main()
{
        int option;
        do
        {
                printf("\n\n *****MAIN MENU *****"); 
                printf("\n 1: Create a list"); 
                printf("\n 2: Display the list");
                printf("\n 3: Add a node at the beginning");
                printf("\n 4: Add a node at the end"); 
                printf("\n 5: Add a node before a given node"); 
                printf("\n 6: Add a node after a given node"); 
                printf("\n 7: Delete a node from the beginning"); 
                printf("\n 8: Delete a node from the end"); 
                printf("\n 9: Delete a node before a given node"); 
                printf("\n 10: Delete a node after a given node"); 
                printf("\n 11: Delete the entire list"); 
                printf("\n 12: EXIT"); 
                printf("\n\n Enter your option : "); 
                scanf("%d", &option); 
                switch(option)
                {
                        case 1: start = create_ll(start); 
                                printf("\n DOUBLY LINKED LIST CREATED"); 
                                break; 
                        case 2: start = display(start); 
                                break; 
                        case 3: start = insert_beg(start); 
                                break; 
                        case 4: start = insert_end(start); 
                                break; 
                        case 5: start = insert_before(start); 
                                break; 
                        case 6: start = insert_after(start); 
                                break; 
                        case 7: start = delete_beg(start); 
                                break; 
                        case 8: start = delete_end(start); 
                                break; 
                        case 9: start = delete_before(start); 
                                break; 
                        case 10: start = delete_after(start);
                                break; 
                        case 11: start = delete_list(start); 
                                printf("\n DOUBLY LINKED LIST DELETED"); 
                                break;
                    }
        }while(option != 12);
        getch(); 
        return 0;
} 
struct node *create_ll(struct node *start) 
{
        struct node *new_node, *ptr; 
        int num; 
        printf("\n Enter –1 to end"); 
        printf("\n Enter the data : "); 
        scanf("%d", &num); 
        while(num != -1) 
        {
                if(start == NULL)
                {
                        new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        new_node -> prev = NULL; 
                        new_node -> data = num; 
                        new_node -> next = NULL; 
                        start = new_node;
                }
                else
                {
                        ptr=start;
                        new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        new_node->data=num; 
                        while(ptr->next!=NULL) 
                                ptr = ptr->next; 
                        ptr->next = new_node; 
                        new_node->prev=ptr; 
                        new_node->next=NULL;
                } 
                printf("\n Enter the data : "); 
                scanf("%d", &num);
        } 
        return start;
}
struct node *display(struct node *start) 
{
        struct node *ptr; 
        ptr=start; 
        while(ptr!=NULL) 
        {
                printf("\t %d", ptr -> data);
                ptr = ptr -> next; 
        } 
        return start;
} 
struct node *insert_beg(struct node *start) 
{
        struct node *new_node; 
        int num; 
        printf("\n Enter the data : "); 
        scanf("%d", &num); 
        new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
        new_node -> data = num;
        start -> prev = new_node; 
        new_node -> next = start; 
        new_node -> prev = NULL; 
        start = new_node; 
        return start;
} 
struct node *insert_end(struct node *start) 
{
        struct node *ptr, *new_node; 
        int num; 
        printf("\n Enter the data : "); 
        scanf("%d", &num); 
        new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
        new_node -> data = num; 
        ptr=start; 
        while(ptr -> next != NULL) 
                ptr = ptr -> next; 
        ptr -> next = new_node; 
        new_node -> prev = ptr; 
        new_node -> next = NULL; 
        return start;
} 
struct node *insert_before(struct node *start) 
{
        struct node *new_node, *ptr; 
        int num, val; 
        printf("\n Enter the data : "); 
        scanf("%d", &num); 
        printf("\n Enter the value before which the data has to be inserted : "); 
        scanf("%d", &val); 
        new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
        new_node -> data = num; 
        ptr = start; 
        while(ptr -> data != val) 
                ptr = ptr -> next; 
        new_node -> next = ptr; 
        new_node -> prev = ptr-> prev; 
        ptr -> prev -> next = new_node; 
        ptr -> prev = new_node; 
        return start;
} 
struct node *insert_after(struct node *start) 
{
        struct node *new_node, *ptr; 
        int num, val; 
        printf("\n Enter the data : "); 
        scanf("%d", &num); 
        printf("\n Enter the value after which the data has to be inserted : "); 
        scanf("%d", &val); 
        new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
        new_node -> data = num; 
        ptr = start; 
        while(ptr -> data != val) 
                ptr = ptr -> next; 
        new_node -> prev = ptr; 
        new_node -> next = ptr -> next; 
        ptr -> next -> prev = new_node; 
        ptr -> next = new_node; 
        return start;
}
struct node *delete_beg(struct node *start) 
{ 
        struct node *ptr; 
        ptr = start; 
        start = start -> next; 
        start -> prev = NULL; 
        free(ptr); 
        return start;
} 
struct node *delete_end(struct node *start) 
{ 
        struct node *ptr; 
        ptr = start; 
        while(ptr -> next != NULL) 
                ptr = ptr -> next; 
        ptr -> prev -> next = NULL; 
        free(ptr); 
        return start;
} 
struct node *delete_after(struct node *start) 
{
        struct node *ptr, *temp;
        int val;
        printf("\n Enter the value after which the node has to deleted : ");
        scanf("%d", &val); 
        ptr = start; 
        while(ptr -> data != val) 
                ptr = ptr -> next; 
        temp = ptr -> next; 
        ptr -> next = temp -> next; 
        temp -> next -> prev = ptr; 
        free(temp); 
        return start;
} 
struct node *delete_before(struct node *start) 
{
        struct node *ptr, *temp; 
        int val; 
        printf("\n Enter the value before which the node has to deleted : "); 
        scanf("%d", &val); 
        ptr = start; 
        while(ptr -> data != val)
                ptr = ptr -> next; 
        temp = ptr -> prev; 
        if(temp == start)
                start = delete_beg(start); 
        else 
        {
                ptr -> prev = temp -> prev;
                temp -> prev -> next = ptr; 
        } 
        free(temp); 
        return start;
} 
struct node *delete_list(struct node *start) 
{
        while(start != NULL) 
                start = delete_beg(start);
        return start; 
}
```

and my terminal says..

cd "/Users/andysohn/Desktop/Suits/" && gcc tempCodeRunnerFile.c -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "/Users/andysohn/Desktop/Suits/"tempCodeRunnerFile
andysohn@Andyui-MacBookPro Suits % cd "/Users/andysohn/Desktop/Suits/" && gcc tempCodeRunnerFile.c -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "/Users/andysohn/Desktop/Suits/"tempCodeRunnerFile
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_stdscr", referenced from:
_main in tempCodeRunnerFile-7f7d00.o
"_wgetch", referenced from:
_main in tempCodeRunnerFile-7f7d00.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

please help me..

Comment: Can you add your code please ?

Comment: You forgot to copy/paste your code into a code-formatting block.  Also, don't post pictures of text; do the same for your error messages, copy-pasting the text inside triple-backticks for code formatting.

Comment: guys I posted the code and the error message!

Comment: This looks far from minimal for a [mcve].  Surely a much simpler program could reproduce the same error message.  Your code doesn't directly use `stdscr` or `wgetch`, although you do have a normal `getch`, so I'd start by just compiling a program that did `int main() { return getch(); }` to see if it would link.

Comment: Is `getch` from curses.h? Yup, man page says it is.  You included the header but didn't link the library with `-lcurses`.

Comment: This is a code directly from a textbook, 'data structures using c'

Comment: how do I link the library with -lcurses??